# python inheritance __init__ confusion

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using python 2.7 and confused about inheritance concept.

I want to make a script that can download from various manga (japanese comic site)

Every manga site uses a different method to save their file. So i have a "Manga_site" class and class called "mangacanblog" (this is a website manga).

Every manga site has a: homepage,collection,page,etc. and it's all different for each site. my question is. is this script correct to store those homepage,collection_page,etc variable? or should I use self.homepage in mangacanblog class and not in the Manga_site class?

```
class Manga_site:

    def __init__(self,homepage,collection_page,base_manga_page,manga_title = ""):
        self.homepage = homepage
        self.collection_page = collection_page
        self.base_manga_page = base_manga_page
        self.manga_title = manga_title


class Mangacanblog(Manga_site):

    def __init__(self,manga_title):
        homepage = bloglink
        collection_page = collectionpagelink
        manga_title = manga_title.lower()
        base_manga_page = basepagelink
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Mangacanblog`'s `__init__()` function you are just setting local variables `homepage`, `collection_page`, etc, not instance variables, to make them instance variables you have to use `self.` , and this needs to be used in both super class as well as subclass.

But a better thing to do would be to call `super(Manga_site).__init__()`  to let the super class handle its initialization, and then you can initialize sub class just the way you want to.

But for this, you would need to define `Manga_site` as a new style class, by inheriting from `object` class. Example -

```
class Manga_site(object):

    def __init__(self,homepage,collection_page,base_manga_page,manga_title = ""):
        self.homepage = homepage
        self.collection_page = collection_page
        self.base_manga_page = base_manga_page
        self.manga_title = manga_title


class Mangacanblog(Manga_site):

    def __init__(self,manga_title):
        super(Mangacanblog, self).__init__(bloglink, collectionpagelink, basepagelink, manga_title.lower())
```

I have guessing you would define `bloglink` and `collectionpagelink` , before you use them in the subclass.

---

But this given, from the example you have given, what you are trying to achieve may be to use `objects` of class, and not inheritence.

Inheritence is used when the subclass has extra attributes/properties and extra methods.

You create different objects of same class if you want to store different data in them. Example -

```
class Manga_site:

    def __init__(self,homepage,collection_page,base_manga_page,manga_title = ""):
        self.homepage = homepage
        self.collection_page = collection_page
        self.base_manga_page = base_manga_page
        self.manga_title = manga_title

mangacanblog = Manga_site('<homepage url>','<collection_page>',....)
anothermangasite = Manga_site('<another url>',....)
```

Then you can use these objects anyway you want to.

Comment: by the way, i don't really get what you mean by i am using object
i try to make this script extendable so that every time i found a new website i just make another subclass of the mangasite, am i doing the wrong way?

Comment: No, I do not mean you are using object, I mean from your examples it seems like you want to use objects instead of subclass

Comment: To answer that, would the new subclass have any different attributes/property? or different methods? Or would everything be inherited from the super class? Would the only difference be data?

Comment: oh now i get it, the reason i use sub class is because every mangasite have different method of storing, so i should use different function to get the image from the site right? can i achieve it just by using one class?

Comment: for example, there is a mangasite that use encryption, there is a mangasite that just literally store the images in a folder, etc

Comment: No, then you should use subclasses, then you are doing good I believe.

Comment: @AnandSKumar aren't you supposed to pass on the `mangacanblog` arguments to `super`? I mean the class the `manga_site` attributes don't have any default values. so wouldn't this answer be wrong?

Comment: @Zion which part of the answer are you talking about?

Comment: In first part, i am passing `Mangacanblog` to `super()` call, as is needed by `super()` in Python 2.x - `super(Mangacanblog, self)` . Other than that I do not understand what you are saying , can you clarify?

Comment: @AnandSKumar yeah the `_init_` on mangacanblog there aren't enough arguments in there for you to pass to it's superclass because the superclass which is `manga_site` has 3 arguments that doesn't  have a default value and you only passed one value to it which is `manga_title`. wouldn't that mean that `collectionpagelink`, `basepagelink`, and `bloglink` be undefined?

Comment: Which code are you looking at? I have passed all the arguments , I also mentioned that - *I have guessing you would define bloglink and collectionpagelink , before you use them in the subclass.* . And I have passed in 4 arguments - `super(Mangacanblog, self).__init__(bloglink, collectionpagelink, basepagelink, manga_title.lower())` . Obviously, the OP is using some other method to determine the baselink and other links for the subclass (and not making the user to pass it in for each object) .

Comment: @AnandSKumar oh ok if thats the case then forget what I said. maybe it's the code but then again maybe it's just me